# Static assert that source code does not change in C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform, backwards-compatibility, static-assert

Say I have a method that must not change. Is there a way in C++ to create a compile time error (or runtime if compile time is impossible) if such a method changes?

There are many uses of such a method (consider ficky threading or security issues that you don't want a novice co-worker changing). My particular use case is in maintaining backwards compatibility where some old methods such as persistent data deserializers must not change.

I'm imagining something like the following:

```
static_assert(chechsumOfBelowFunction() != 0x123,
  "You changed the method! We can't do this because...")
std::string getRelaseDateForVersion3()
{
    // This should never change because "Version 3" was
    // only released once!
    return "2014-Jan-01";
}
```

Where `checksumOfBelowFunction()` computes a checksum or some other unique representation of the function (preferably cross platform) at compile time and `0x123` is the known reference checksum of what the function must stay as. Note that I've taken quite a bit or liberty with pseudo code but I hope I convey what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Put it in its own file, compute a  hash of it, and then check in each build if that files' hash does not match what is expected?

Comment: How do you define a method changing/not changing? Is it just the source code that should not change, or the _behavior_? What if the method calls another function that was modified, but itself is otherwise unchanged? Anyway, this sounds more like a job for your build/version control system than the C++ compiler.

Comment: @Sergey Klevstov, preferably behavior but source code would be acceptable.

Comment: @NathanOliver that feels clunky to me (I don't want the language dictating what files I have to make). I'd prefer to avoid tying the safety check to the build system as this is a check on the _soruce_, not the _build_! That said, it is better than nothing and barring other answers I will looking doing that. I doubt it would be too hard to do in CMake. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Stick it in its own source tree with different developer permissions then release it as an object / library?

Comment: the best way is to write a unit-test for the function

Answer (score 1):

> Say I have a method that must not change. Is there a way in C++ to create a compile time error (or runtime if compile time is impossible) if such a method changes?

**No**, there is no way (especially if you care about behavior, not source code). Remember that equality of behavior of two functions is an undecidable problem (equivalent to the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). In other words, [equivalence of lambda terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Undecidability_of_equivalence) (i.e. of two C++ programs or subprograms or functions) is **undecidable**.

And your *requirement* (of a function or method that "should not change") is *ill-defined*. What if the C++ source file is just re-indented? Or a typo in some comment is corrected? Or the name of some local variable has simply changed? Or for readability reasons a `for` loop is replaced with some equivalent `while`? Or some linear scan replaced by a more efficient dichotomical approach; etc....!

Perhaps you could put that function in its own source file, compute some cryptographic hash of it, and put that in your build process (e.g. your `Makefile` for [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software))).

You could spend months of work on more fancy approaches (e.g. customize your GCC compiler, perhaps with some extension in [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) or some GCC [plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html#Plugins), to compute  inside your `g++` compiler an hash of the [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) AST of your function which should stay the same, etc...). I am not sure it is worth the effort.

---

You could have some timestamp machinery.

In many of my [`Makefile`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/Makefile)-s I generate a `__timestamp.c`  file e.g. like:

```
__timestamp.c: Makefile
    @(date +'const char bismon_timestamp[]="%c";'; \ 
     date +'%n const unsigned long bismon_timelong=%sL;' > __timestamp.tmp)
    @(echo -n 'const char bismon_lastgitcommit[]="' ; \
       git log --format=oneline --abbrev=12 --abbrev-commit -q  \
         | head -1 | tr -d '\n\r\f\"\\\\' ; \
       echo '";') >> __timestamp.tmp
    @(echo -n 'const char bismon_lastgittag[]="'; \
          (git describe --abbrev=0 --all || echo '*notag*') \
          | tr -d '\n\r\f\"\\\\'; echo '";') >> __timestamp.tmp
    @(echo -n 'const char bismon_checksum[]="'; cat bismon.h \
      $(BM_HEADERS) $(CSOURCES) | $(MD5SUM) \
     | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '\n\r\f\"\\' ; echo '";') >> __timestamp.tmp
    @(echo -n 'const char bismon_directory[]="'; \
       /bin/pwd | tr -d '\n\\"' ; echo '";') >> __timestamp.tmp
    @(echo -n 'const char bismon_makefile[]="'; \
      echo -n  $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))); \
      echo '";') >> __timestamp.tmp
    @mv __timestamp.tmp __timestamp.c
```

and then I link `__timestamp.o` in  the executable; you could configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool likewise.

---

> I have a method that must not change.

Notice that this is a *social* requirement (related to code reviews), not a software one. Code does change (you want to avoid [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) by [code refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)). Your team should wisely use some good [version control software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) (e.g. [git](http://git-scm.com/)) and you have to somehow trust your colleagues (a malicious competent developer could always do bad things).

<sup>(it looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info); perhaps you are seeking a purely technical solution to a social problem)</sup>

> My particular use case is in maintaining backwards compatibility where some old methods such as persistent data deserializers must not change.

The usual way is to record in the persisted data a *version* (or signature) of the used format. For inspiration look into [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) or simply the [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) version declaration ([XMLDecl](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl)).

<sup>(papers on [dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating) could interest you)</sup>